# fetch n-elements from a list Racket

Tags: scheme, racket

How can I fetch n-elements from a list,
I know about first, rest etc, but what if I want the first 3 elements in a list,

I.E 
(get-first 3 (list 1 2 3 4 5 6)) -> (list 1 2 3)

(get-first 5 (list 54 33 2 12 11 2 1 22 3 44)) -> (list 54 33 2 12 11)

This is not homework, but this code will help me complete the bigger picture of an assignment, I am really stuck and just need a few hints.
I am not allowed to use Lambda or build-list and no recursion, I somehow need to b able to do this with just map, filter, foldr etc...

Comment: You can do it using `take` from `racket/list`. If you can’t use `take`, which seems implied by your question, please make it clear exactly what your requirements are (using `take` is the answer to your question as currently phrased).

Comment: "I am not allowed to use lambda or recursion..." #triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was mentioned by @AlexisKing, you can simply use the [`take`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Flist..rkt%29._take%29%29) procedure that's built-in in Racket:

```
(take '(1 2 3 4 5 6) 3)
=> '(1 2 3)

(take '(54 33 2 12 11 2 1 22 3 44) 5)
=> '(54 33 2 12 11)
```

If for some reason that's not allowed you can still roll your own version using higher-order procedures and no explicit recursion, but *do* notice that not using `lambda` is impossible, the allowed procedures you mention (`map`, `filter`, `foldr`) *all receive a* `lambda` *as a parameter*, and anyway *all* procedures in Scheme are `lambda`s under the hood.

Here's a contrived solution, passing an accumulator that remembers in what index we're in the input list while traversing it, and building the output list in the `cdr` part. It can't be done without using a `lambda`, but if it bothers you to see it there, extract it to a helper procedure and pass it along:

```
(define (get-first n lst)
  (reverse
   (cdr
    (foldr (lambda (e acc)
             (if (= (car acc) n)
                 acc
                 (cons (add1 (car acc))
                       (cons e (cdr acc)))))
           '(0 . ())
           (reverse lst)))))
```

It still works as expected, but never do such a complicated thing when a built-in procedure will do the same:

```
(get-first 3 '(1 2 3 4 5 6))
=> '(1 2 3)

(get-first 5 '(54 33 2 12 11 2 1 22 3 44))
=> '(54 33 2 12 11)
```